# Windows7 command prompt show number of objects as list from dir command

Tags: windows-7, amazon-s3, dir, recursive, list

I'm using Windows7, and I want to know the number of files (or objects) for comparison to objects in Amazon S3 buckets.  I'm not interested in size, as the size can differ between file types.

I want to do this as a list from the command prompt (starting with dir) so that I can output this from several different computers to a spreadsheet so I can verify vs s3.  This output out be dir>.txt where the info from dir would not only be date | time | type (directory or file) | filename | plus number of objects.

I have hundreds of folders on dozens of computers to access, so I'm looking for something 1) simple and 2) that doesn't require typing in the name of each folder individually 3) that will search recursively inside each folder and subfolder 4) that generates a list output. The dir command alone is 90% of the way there, it just lacks the number of files inside folders, which hopefully is an easy output to generate.

Please no linux or Powershell recommendations as they can't be applied.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question, and point out an example of expected output, where it is possible to better understand what you hope to get, once done, I believe you will get a better answer.

Comment: Here is an example of the current output from a win7 dir command:  
07/30/2020  04:22 PM    <DIR>          directory1. 
07/30/2020  05:07 PM    <DIR>          directory2. 
07/30/2020  04:57 PM    <DIR>          directory3. 

Here is what I would like to get—list format for output as a .txt file. 
07/30/2020  04:22 PM    <DIR>          directory1 1000 files. 
07/30/2020  05:07 PM    <DIR>          directory2 1500 files. 
07/30/2020  04:57 PM    <DIR>          directory3 1600 files.

Comment: get the wc command and `do dir /b | wc -l`

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I adjusted to what I could understand, if you need to adjust more, please let me know ...

Comment: why no Powershell? Vista+ always have powershell included so it should be used instead of the dreaded cmd[

Comment: this is really close, but it walks through all the subfolders.  Is there a way to set the depth at 1 but still be recursive for all the folders and objects inside?
    [@for /d /r %I in (*)do @for /f %i in ('dir/b "%~I\"^|find/c /v ""')do @echo\%~tI ^<DIR^> %~nxI %~i files]

Comment: when I try this: for /d /r %%I in (*)do for /f %%i in ('dir/b "%%~I"^|find/c /v ""
')do >>"%temp%\_output_.csv" echo\%%~tI,^<DIR^>,%%~nxI,%%~i,files   
 

the result is "%%I was unexpected at this time."

Comment: I didn't know if I could run powershell on these machines--turns out that I could use a powershell solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
@echo off & cd "Filepath" & for /f "tokens=* delims=*" %a in ('dir /s /b') do (set "name=%~fa" & set "date=%~za" & set "type=%~xa" & echo %date% %type% %name% >>"Output.txt")
```

Here replace "Filepath" with the folder path and output.txt with the output text file. If you need to add more properties, ping me in comment. Run this from Cmd.

Comment: When I run this, all I get is today's date, %type% %name% over and over again. There is no useable information in terms of folder names or number of objects in the folders

Answer (score 0):

```all-file-bat
@echo off & title <nul & title ...\%~nx0

cd/d "%~dp0" && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>nul del/q /f "%temp%\_output_.csv" .\output.csv 2>&1 

for /d /r %%I in (*)do for /f %%i in ('dir/b "%%~I"^|find/c /v ""
')do >>"%temp%\_output_.csv" echo\%%~tI,^<DIR^>,%%~nxI,%%~i,files 

<con: >nul move "%temp%\_output_.csv" .\output.csv 2>&1 & endlocal
```

---

Getting a listing of items folders, files, object totals, dates <strike>without a predefined layout</strike>... is not something that can be easy to achieve, especially when we don't know what is simple for those who ask.

You can try:

- For **[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)**:

---

```all-file-bat
@for /d /r %I in (*)do @for /f %i in ('dir/b "%~I\"^|find/c /v ""')do @echo\%~tI ^<DIR^> %~nxI %~i files
```

---

- For file **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**

---

```all-file-bat
@echo off 

rem :: go to your destination folder
cd /d "%~dp0"&& setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem :: remove any files from previous runs (if exist)
>nul del/q /f "%temp%\_output_.csv" .\output.csv 2>&1 

rem :: use a `for` loop to recursively folder and a second loop to
rem :: count your files in the current folder in the first `for` loop
for /d /r %%I in (*)do for /f %%i in ('dir/b "%%~I"^|find/c /v ""
')do >>"%temp%\_output_.csv" echo\%%~tI,^<DIR^>,%%~nxI,%%~i,files 


rem :: save the results to the temporary folder, then move to the current 
<con: >nul move "%temp%\_output_.csv" .\output.csv 2>&1 & endlocal
```

---

- Some options using substitution of `for` variable:

```all-file-bat
    %%~i   - expands %%i removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %%~fi  - expands %%i to a fully qualified path name only
    %%~ti  - expands %%i to date/time of file only
    %%~ni  - expands %%i to a file name only
    %%~xi  - expands %%i to a file extension only
    
    %%~nxi => expands %%~i to a file name and extension
```

---

- *The option **`/d /r` is undocumented**, but can be a useful combination, while it will **recurse through all subfolders** the wildcard will only match against Folder/Directory names (**not filenames**).*

  - **[Sources ss64.com | `For /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Cd](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**

  [√] **[Echo](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)**

  [√] **[Move](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)**

  [√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For /D /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && | ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[`Enable/DisableDelayedExpansion` | `Enable/DisableExtensions`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**

Comment: Maybe this line in my original post was confusing. Currently dir outputs date | time | type (directory or file) | filename.  All I need is for this list to also include number of objects contained in a folder.

Comment: @Jordan Plz, check last edit... thank you